# Understanding delayed_job status

Tags: ruby, delayed-job

I've implemented long-running tasks in my Rails app using [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) along with [delayed_job_web](https://github.com/ejschmitt/delayed_job_web). My delayed_job configuration instructs jobs to be attempted once, and for failures to be retained:

**config/initializers/delayed_job.rb:**

```
Delayed::Worker.max_attempts = 1
Delayed::Worker.destroy_failed_jobs = false
```

I tried 2 test jobs that automatically raised errors, in order to see how failures behave. What I get is the following:

[image]

My expectation was that Failed jobs would have a count of 2, but that **Enqueued** / **Working** / **Pending** would all be 0. I can't find any documentation on what determines whether a job is **Enqueued** / **Working** / **Pending**, or even what the difference between **Working** and **Pending** is (the web interface describes both lists as  "contains jobs currently being processed".)

Can anyone provide some clarity?

Comment: How did you get that table? I can't find a nice way monitor the queue..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check https://github.com/ejschmitt/delayed_job_web/blob/master/lib/delayed_job_web/application/app.rb , you see the following (starting line 114):

```
when :working
  'locked_at is not null'
when :failed
  'last_error is not null'
when :pending
  'attempts = 0'
end
```

1. Enqueued would be the total number of delayed jobs, i.e. `Delayed::Job.count`
2. Working jobs are those that have been locked by the delayed_job process and are currently being worked.
3. Failed are those that have a `last_error`
4. Pending are those jobs that have never been attempted.

Comment: @Abdo- Thanks, this all makes sense except for the working status. If a job has failed, and max_attempts = 1, why would the job still be considered working/locked?

Comment: I agree with you; however, this is how they do it in their source code. You can fork their source and update it if it's bothering you and pull your gem in your Gemfile :-)